# Angular-meteor tutorial WhatsApp is not working in IOS 9.3

Tags: ios, angular-meteor

I'm trying to deploy Whatsapp tutorial application shown in this page (http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/meteor/layout) in IOS 9.3, but I'm not able to run properly due to a navigation problem. The behaviour is very weird, you have to click more than one time an action button in order to navigate to other page. Also, the icons in the tab control are not visible.

Somebody knows How can I fix this issue?

I appreciate your help,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I was trying to find a solution in different forums, I did this fix that it seems to work for me.
https://github.com/juancho559/whatsapp